# how to store data from yaml file

Tags: c#, yaml

I am doing a project in C# and it requires to read a yaml file.
My question is how can we extract data from yaml file and store it into arrays or something else?

Here is the yaml file sample I need to deal with. How can we read data and store into different array `point1[]` `point2[]` ...

```
samples:
    - time: 2014-03-02T23:20:19+00:00
      longitude: 147.311547
      latitude: -42.629483
      temperature: 27
      acceleration: [1.3e1, -1.8, 1.2E1]
      magnetic_field: [25, 45e0, 15]
      uv: 6
      battery:

    - time: 2014-03-01T23:20:19+00:00
      longitude: -87.700582
      latitude: 41.953825
      temperature: 27
      acceleration: [2e1, 5.3, -1.7E1]
      magnetic_field: [25, 45e0, 15]
      uv: 6.5
      battery:

    - time:...
      ...
```

Comment: You could check out http://yaml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Have you tried to find some library that does that? Look at main YAML page ( http://www.yaml.org/ ) ...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this by default. 
However there are multiple extensions and plugins for this.

I did a quick google and this came up: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34423c06-f756-4721-8394-bc3d23b91ca7

It is his first release with no reviews.
but you can try it if that doesn't work you can try the allready suggested:
http://yaml.codeplex.com/

I hope this helps. let us know!

Good luck with your program.